# Redshift Stored Procedure being Aborted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have an S3 bucket that receives files (`FILE_A` and `FILE_B`) at almost the exact same time of day.

I have a lambda function that is trigged when these files are uploaded to S3. The lambda function will call one of two stored procedures based upon the type of file.

The lambda function simply calls the appropriate stored procedure using the Redshift Data API then exits.

```
IF (FILE_A) {
  CALL SP_A(FILE_A.name)
}
ELSE IF (FILE_B) {
  CALL SP_B(FILE_B.name)
}
```

The two stored procedures are nearly identical, they just operate on a different set of tables. As each stored procedure progresses, they log status information via a stored procedure to a shared `LOG` table in Redshift.

The structure of each stored procedure is basically...

```
LOG('sp_a started')
LOG('sp_a truncate table_a_1')

TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_A_1

LOG('sp_a copy started')
COPY INTO TABLE_A_1 FROM S3 FILE_A

LOG('sp_a insert table_a_2')
INSERT INTO TABLE_A_2 FROM TABLE_A_1

LOG('sp_a delete dupes')
DELETE FROM TABLE_A_3 WHERE SELECT TABLE_A_2

LOG('sp_a insert table_a_3')
INSERT INTO TABLE_A_3 FROM TABLE_A_2

LOG('sp_a finished')
```

The logic for `SP_B` is exactly the same. I can call either stored procedure from the lambda or the Redshift console without issue. Whenever I run the stored procedures individually they work fine.

The problem happens when the stored procedures are started at basically the same time, when FILE_A and FILE_B are uploaded to S3 within milliseconds of each other.

One of the two stored procedures will be aborted by Redshift. The other will run to completion. I haven't 100% verified this, but it seems like the stored procedure that starts first is the one that ends up being aborted by Redshift.

I don't have any transactional boundaries defined in the stored procedures. I'm relying on the implicit transaction that's wrapping the call `CALL SP_A(FILE_A.name)`.

I could rationalize why calls to the same stored procedure at the same time might cause problems, but I can't understand why calls to different stored procedures cause one to fail but not the other. I do not see this problem if they don't run in parallel.

I've searched up and down to try and find where Redshift is logging the reason the stored procedure was aborted, but I can't find anything.

Does anyone know where I might find the Redshift error or have any idea why one of the stored procedures is getting aborted?  Thanks for any help!!!!!

Comment: You're doing a delete and an insert.  You're going to end up with tons of deleted records in your table, and all the new records are going to be unsorted - which makes using Redshift utterly pointless; in that situation its behaviour degenerates to that of Postgres.  What are you doing about vacuum, to sort the table and expunge deleted records?

Comment: Yes, I understand.  The delete is a temporary workaround to deal with some bad data. In fact most of this will probably be changed a lot.  However before moving on,  I'd like to understand what's going on in case there's some basic flaw with running stored procedures concurrently in the way that I am.

Comment: A stored procedure is a transaction; there's nothing special as such about procedures, except that they run as a transactioon.  However, it is certainly possible to use transactions improperly and run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess as to what is happening but the first place to check is stl_error for the operations that are aborted.  This will give you info on what is happening.

Now my guess - I expect you have a Serializable Isolation Violation where the locks created by the 2 stored procedures create a dependency loop.  In this case Redshift has to kill one of the transactions in order to clear the lock loop.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Concurrent_writes.html

This is just a guess so please check stl_error and see what error is being encountered.

Comment: I've looked in the `STL_ERROR` table and haven't found anything associated with the `PID`.  I've looked at a number of other tables too with no success.  On the Queries and Loads tab, I can see the parent stored procedure call with a status of ABORTED, but none of the child queries have a status other than COMPLETED. 

The two stored procedures operate on different tables, so I wouldn't expect there to be any READ / WRITE contention between them.  They do share the LOG tables, but only INSERTS are performed on the LOG tables.

Comment: Could it be that you are running SP_A twice since both files exist when they run at the same time?  This could cause lock and contention issues.  The second call doesn't make progress due to these issues but Lambda times out and aborts the function.